# How to open wooden villager door in Minecraft on Ipad Tablet

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, touch

My kid is playing Minecraft on an iPad, in creative mode, and comes to a village, where villagers move in/out of a wooden door.

However, for the life of me... Absolutely nothing works to open the door. We tried slow tapping the door, quick tapping the door, double tapping the door, with nothing in hand, etc.

What are we doing wrong?

Are doors in villager houses not openable? I can see villagers go in/out of the house.

Answer (score 2):

The wooden doors are able to be opened by simply tapping them on the screen. If you aren't able to open doors even if you do tap them, try checking your **player permissions** by pressing the pause button (On the top middle) and then on the right side of the screen you should see the player name along with a symbol. Click the symbol, and make sure it is set to anything other than "Visitor".

Comment: Thank you. I will try checking player permissions and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the player's permission to interact with doors you can change it in the settings, but first, try another door that you have placed first.